# How do I set a cookie to expire 30 minutes after a session ends?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies

I want to set a cookie to allow the user access to a download behind a gate form throughout the site, but if they navigate away from the site or close the browser and come back within half an hour they should still be able to access the download.

Currently the cookie is just set on form submit (using https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) with no expiry (ie. a sesson cookie). If they come back after ending the session (within 30 minutes), the cookie needs to be refreshed for the new session.

Comment: set the expiry date in window.onbeforeunload

Comment: I'd set the expiration to 30 minutes from "now" every time the user interacts with the site (on form submit, on page load or whatever it is that makes the download available), then another one on page close.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using js-cookie client side (in the browser)? A robust solution should be implemented server side, perhaps checking a session cookie against a server side record of the time the form was submitted. A client side solution would be relatively easily vulnerable to abuse by a bad actor using a browser debugger.